# PhoneGap jQuery POST not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, cordova

Good evening,

I was trying a long time with different syntaxes but haven't got it working:
Everything is running on PhoneGap. I get the `console_log` before `$.ajax..`, but not any error or output after it.
After click on "Submit" this JS code is executed:

```
 console.log(in_mail + " " + in_text);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: "mail="+in_mail+'&amp;text='+in_text,
            url: 'http://example.com/comment.php',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Your comment was successfully added');
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error adding your comment');
            }
        });
 console.log("POST done");
```

Comment: Are you able to test in a regular browser to see what output comment.php is returning?

Comment: This may not fix anything, but you should set the data parameter like this `data: { mail: in_mail, text: in_text},`

Comment: adding the "data" variable in error function parenthesis might solve the problem.
error: function(data){
---
---
}

Comment: The code works fine, i get the output from the PHP "ok" in my console

Comment: @Raghav Bhushan: But I don't even get the alert in the error function...

Comment: javascript remains silent even if an error occurs. try it first and then tell if does not work.

Comment: Ok, now I get this error: `2012-06-30 22:02:11.085 Rhythm[13973:15b03] [INFO] {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you are executing this script via submit button you should consider returning true on success and false on error.
2. Your "POST DONE" would execute before the success or error functions would be invoked because post is asynchronous.

I have reproduced the example with jsFiddle you can find it here http://jsfiddle.net/jUBMN/